# Document.write brokes page

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox

I've prepared view that loads aync another view and then replace current with document.write (yes, I want to replace whole page!):

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: myUrl,
data: null,
async: true,        
success: function (result) {

    document.close();
    document.open();
    document.write(result);
    document.close();
},
error: function (req, status, error) {
    $("#loading-div").html("error");
}
});
```

The content is full view with own scripts and css styles. When using IE or Chrome everything works fine. When I load page within firefox, loaded page via document.write doesn't seems to be working properly - especially scripts (some works, some don't).

I can't use innerHTML due to scripts that are not evaluated.

Why it doesn't work properly only in Firefox (even IE can handle it!)?

Comment: Look into `.append()` or figure out how to use `.html()`. There's almost never a good reason to use `document.write`, especially after the `document` has loaded

Comment: I don't want to append anything. I want to **replace whole page**. Unfortunately, `.html()` can't handle with scripts. I've already tried (tried to manually load scripts)

Comment: Why? Redirect, use an iframe, or partially load the page into a part of your site. And you can always use `.empty()` before `.append()`

Comment: Can't use redirect and iframe. I've used ajax due to load view async (it takes lot of time). I think that `.append` like `.html()` omits the scripts in a response.

Comment: I can't use partial view, because view like I said contains lots of scripts. Can't load manually scripts, there is too much dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification requires `document.open` to create a new global.  Firefox does that.  Chrome does not; I can't speak for IE.

So if you're depending on the old global sticking around, your script will work in Chrome but not Firefox.

Comment: OK, i need to find other solution. I've tried to use innerHtml in order to set content and run scripts manually, bot some functions don't work properly. I've also tried to use jQuery, but it fails while parsing response.